# Make jQuery animate loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are other and more preferred methods, but I'm trying to give a div img a bounce effect using jQuery.

I'm trying to loop

```
 $('#downarrow').animate({bottom:'4px'});
  $('#downarrow').animate({bottom:'0px'});
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldnt this be easier in css keyframes animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple solution:

```
function bounceUp(){
    $('#downarrow').animate({bottom:'4px'}, 1000, bounceDown);
}
function bounceDown(){
    $('#downarrow').animate({bottom:'0px'}, 1000, bounceUp);
}

bounceUp();
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/nd8kf61s/

Comment: Just what I needed. I'll accept this in 8 minutes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to `addClass` or `toggleClass`. But this approach using the css animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.arrow').toggleClass('upp');
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.upp {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1.5s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 1.5s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 10px
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 10px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">
  hey
</div>
```